# django problem with shared memcache nodes

Tags: django, memcached

i have two django instances running on two servers and i am using memcached to cache some data in my applicationa.
each server have it's own memcached installed, i want to both of my applications have access to both caches but i cant't. when i set a values from one application in cache other application cant access it

my memcached instances are running as root, also i have tried memcache and other users but it didn't fix the problem.
for testing i used django shell, import cache class:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
```

set a value in cache :

```
cache.set('foo', 'bar', 3000)
```

and tried to get value from my other Django instance :

```
cache.get('foo')
```

but it returns nothing!

here is my settings.py file :

```py
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'LOCATION': [
                     'first app server ip:port',
                     'second app server ip:port']

    }
}
```

and my memcached.conf(comments deletede):

```
-d

logfile /var/log/memcache/memcached.log

# -v

-vv

-m 512

-p 11211

-u root

-l 192.168.174.160

# -c 1024

# -k

# -M

# -r

-P /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid
```

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to use PyLibMCCache?

Comment: i have read some benchmarks that says it have a better performance than python memcached https://plot.ly/~jensens/36.embed, but i have also tried python-memcached as my connector but it didn't solved the problem

Comment: order of location in settings must be the same in all servers. is it like this?

Comment: oh my God, you saved my day, that solved my problem, but how should i know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of location in settings must be the same in all servers. Could you please check if they are same?